# Как обновить PHP в XAMPP?

Tags: php

Использую XAMPP последней версии для Windows. В отличии от XAMPP для Linux в нём более старые версии модулей: PHP 5.1.6 и phpMyAdmin 2.8.2.4.

Мне нужно обновить PHP до более новой версии (минимум 5.2), я скачал последнюю 5.4.0

Сделал бэкап папки xampp/php, удалил там всё, залил новую версию, потом вернул php.ini от старой (пробовал и оставлять новый).

После перезапуска XAMPP появляются сообщения об ошибках:

> Точка входа в процедуру ...... не найдена в библиотеке DLL php5ts.dll

И так несколько сообщений, с

> ap___php_slprintf
>
> zend___eval_stringf
>
> ___safe_erealloc
>
> _mysqlnd___fetch_lengths

Думаю, суть в не этих названиях.

P.S.: прошу не предлагать использовать отдельно компоненты вместо сборки, я может и перейду на данный вариант, но просто сейчас мне нужно решение проблемы для XAMPP.  Заранее благодарен.

Comment: Кажется ответ на вопрос есть тут: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4792439

Answer (score 1):

```
DLL php5ts.dll // выскакивает из-за того что ты все удалил из папки и апач не может найти библиотеку.
```

ну так апачу нужно сказать какую библиотеку грузить для php так что тебе в файл конфигурации апача. и там поменять

```
LoadModule php5_module "/usr/local/php5/php5apache2_2.dll"  // это для примера. указать именно нужную и новую DLLку
```

Comment: Спасибо. Но я не совсем понял, во-первых,>из-за того что ты все удалил из папки и апач не может найти библиотеку.Я же ведь залил новую то версию PHP. Библиотека php5ts.dll там лежит.Во-вторых, второе я сделал - указал LoadModule с нужным путём и этим как у вас именем DLL-ки (думаю, что надо её, т.к. у меня Apache 2.2.3, а не 2.3.*). Но тогда при запуске XAMPP в консоли сначала пишется, что данный модуль уже загружен, а потом Apache и вовсе вылетает.